# Failing a restore of a transaction when a transaction doesn't exist with in app purchases and objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, in-app-purchase

I have an app with in-app purchases being developed now. The entire purchasing process is working and the restore is also working when there's an active purchase with the Apple ID. However, when it comes to a user clicking on the "Restore Purchase" `UIButton` when there isn't a purchase active with the signed in Apple account, I would like to handle that situation.

In my `AppDelegate`, I have:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{    
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            {
                // unlock the full version
                [self unlockFullVersion:transaction];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
                [self saveReceipts];
                break;
            }

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
            {
                // currently purchasing
                break;
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            {
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction]; 
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];

                break;
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            {
                // it didn't work
                break;
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
            {
                // deferred
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    if (transaction)
    {

        if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.company.Unlimited"])
        {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CheckProVersion" object:self userInfo:nil];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"IAPSuccessful"];


            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        }

            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restore Successful" message:@"Your restore was successful." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"The transaction does not exist");

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restore Unsuccessful" message:@"Your Apple ID doesn't have an active purchase for upgrading to Envylope Pro. " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

In this particular case, the second `UIAlertView` in the `restoreTransaction` method does not get called if transaction doesn't exist.

I have put in a breakpoint and it never gets called. I have put a breakpoint of the `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` case and I'm seeing that, that gets hit when I do not have an active purchase. However, this will then actually do what I want (like a `UIAlertView`) from the `AppDelegate` and I only want this to run in a separate `InAppPurchaseViewController`.

**Issues**

From this `InAppPurchaseViewController` (which is a few screens away), I have a restore `UIButton` and what I want is for a test to be performed during the clicking of the button to see if a transaction for this Apple ID exists. Would something like this be possible?

**Update**

In the `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed`, I have put:

```
        NSString * const SKErrorDomain;
        NSLog(@"The error is %@", SKErrorDomain);
```

I am getting `(null)` as the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this method, it handles the situation when there are no purchases to restore:

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {

   if (queue.transactions.count == 0){
     NSLog(@"The transaction does not exist");

     UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restore Unsuccessful" message:@"Your Apple ID doesn't have an active purchase for upgrading to Envylope Pro. " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
     [alertView show];
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response - that's really great to know theres that method available. Do I need to call that from the case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed or somewhere similar? Sorry, the reason I ask is because it's not currently doing anything with that method

Comment: It's a part of SKPaymentTransactionObserver protocol, so it is called automatically when you get response from the App Store . Xcode says: "This method is called after all restorable transactions have been processed by the payment queue." Try to test it on a real device, because simulator usually gets error. You can implement paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError: to check if its true.

Comment: thanks so much - I ran a few debugs and it doesn't get called in the App Delegate for some weird reason. So sorry to ask, how would i implement that restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError? Sorry, sort of a newbie!